# Can't get JPanel to size properly in Swing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, paintcomponent

I'm just learning Swing, and built a sample GUI for myself as practice. Very basic, it has three panels on the West, Center, and East sides of the `JFrame`. In the last panel, there is another panel and a button. The panel is my extension of `JPanel`, `DrawPanel`. It draws a random `Rectangle` every time the button beneath it *Repaint* is clicked. This is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Tester
{
    public static DrawPanel panelEastDrawPanelCenter;

    public static void main()
    {
        Tester gui = new Tester();
        gui.go();
    }
    public void go()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("This is the title");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Create all the Western Panel components
        JPanel panelWest = new JPanel();
        //    panelWest.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JButton panelWestButtonWest = new JButton("Western-most West Button");
        JButton panelWestButtonCenter = new JButton("Western-most Center Button");
        JButton panelWestButtonEast = new JButton("Western-most East Button");

        // Create all Center Panel components
        JPanel panelCenter = new JPanel();
            panelCenter.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
        JButton panelCenterButtonCenter = new JButton("Center Button");

        // Create all East Panel components
        JPanel panelEast = new JPanel();
        panelEastDrawPanelCenter = new DrawPanel();
            panelEastDrawPanelCenter.setSize(50,50);
        JButton panelEastButtonSouth = new JButton("Repaint");
            panelEastButtonSouth.addActionListener(new panelEastButtonSouthListener());

        // Add everything to the GUI
        // West Panel
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.WEST, panelWest);
        panelWest.add(BorderLayout.WEST, panelWestButtonWest);
        panelWest.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panelWestButtonCenter);     
        panelWest.add(BorderLayout.EAST, panelWestButtonEast);

        // Center Panel
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panelCenter);
        panelCenter.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panelCenterButtonCenter);

        // East Panel
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.EAST, panelEast);
        panelEast.add(panelEastDrawPanelCenter);
        panelEast.add(panelEastButtonSouth);

        frame.pack();
        //frame.setSize(frame.getWidth(), 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    class panelEastButtonSouthListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            panelEastDrawPanelCenter.repaint();
        }
    }
    class DrawPanel extends JPanel // JPanel that displays a rectangle upon clicking the button "Repaint"
    {
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE); // Removes previous rectangle
            g.fillRect(0,0, this.getWidth(),this.getHeight());

            g.setColor(randColor()); // Puts a new rectangle on screen, rand size and color
            int height = (int)(Math.random() * this.getHeight());
            int width = (int)(Math.random() * this.getHeight());
            int x = (int)(Math.random() * 20);
            int y = (int)(Math.random() * 20);
            g.fillRect(x,y, height,width);
        }
        public Color randColor()
        {
            int r = (int)(Math.random() * 255);
            int g = (int)(Math.random() * 255);
            int b = (int)(Math.random() * 255);
            return new Color(r, g, b);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I am encountering is that although I explicitly `setSize()` for the `DrawPanel` object (`panelEastDrawPanelCenter`) to 50×50, when I run the program it (`DrawPanel`) is still a small panel next to the button, and panelEast (the container for `DrawPanel` and the button) is still the same width (and will never get wider). I realize that I can say

```
frame.pack();
frame.setSize(frame.getWidth(), 500);
```

if I set the east panel to use a layout of either `BorderLayout` or `BoxLayout`, and this will make the `DrawPanel` display bigger.

1. But I do not understand why setting the size of the `DrawPanel` object does not actually change its size, and why it remains small regardless of me doing `setSize(50,50);`
2. How would I get the middle panel to stop resizing so huge, so that the East panel can resize to be wider? Or how do I resize the East panel?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The BorderLayout respects the preferred width of its west and east components. And it respects the preferred width and height of its center component. So, your DrawPanel should override `getPreferredSize()` and return the appropriate preferred size.

Since it's placed at the center of a BorderLayout which also has a south component, the preferred width of the east panel will be the max of the preferred width of the draw panel and of the button.

Comment: I feel like this works, but is not the most appropriate way to go about doing it. Why not just called `setPreferredSize(Dimension d)` instead of overriding `getPreferredSize()`? :-\.

Comment: @Zéychin I couldn't find that method in the api (i looked under `Component`), and when I tried using it in my code, it says "`no suitable method found for setPreferredSize(int,int)`"

Comment: @Zéychin: Because a component is supposed to know its preferred size (based on the other components it contains, its layout, its fonts, its look 'n feel, etc.), rather than being forced a preferred size from the outside. Each time you use a JButton or a JLabel, you don't set its preferred size do you? This is because the JButton or JLabel returns the appropriate value.

Comment: @Zéychin [maybe you'll accepting...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi), maybe not,

Comment: also, i found `setPreferredSize(Dimension d)` just now, nvm my previous comment...

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `panel.setPerferredSize(Dimension size);`

Answer (score 2):

Try the `setPreferredSize(Dimension)` method instead of `setSize(int, int)` and call a `pack()` after that.